# SQL Developer call procedure on connection to DB

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle's SQL Developer version 4.0.3.16 and I need to automatically execute a procedure every time I connect to a certain database. Does anybody know if there is a way to accomplish this? So far I've checked in the New/Select Database Connection dialog, but don't see it in there.

**Edit**

To clarify, I only want to execute the procedure while connecting to my DB through SQL Developer and not every time a user connects (e.g. through JDBC, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall Oracle's SQL Developer version 4.0.3.17 to get the latest updates to help resolve the connection issue you're experiencing within each and every database you are attempting to access. Once resolved, you will be able to connect automatically each time you start up the environment. If you have any questions related to this topic, shoot me a bird.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you trying to execute a stored procedure every time you login?

If so, you need to make a trigger. Basically you have to create a trigger, when a user establishes an oracle session, to execute your procedure. You can find some [examples](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_builder_sec_audit.htm) here.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edit to my question. I think your suggestion would cause the procedure to be called each time somebody connects to the db, right? I only want to do this when I connect through my client for admin reasons.

Comment: @babernathy if you look at `V$SESSION`, the `program` field shows the  program name. For PL/SQL developer, the PROGRAM name is `plsqldev.exe`  You can use that with the `USERNAME` field. So that way only YOUR username, and YOUR program will activate the trigger.